# syntax error, unexpected token ... what's causing this?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm using SSH Secure Shell to connect to a Linux machine ... when I try to run my script, I keep getting these errors ...

```
[grt@vm]MODE  : D
DATE  : 200806
bash: line 94: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
bash: line 94: syntax error near `+(['
bash: line 94: `        if [ ${#Date} -ne 6 ] || [[ "$Date" != +([0-9]) ]] '
```

My command:

```
ssh grt@$10.*.*.*  'bash -s' < purge.sh $1 $2
```

the few lines of the code where i have this error...:

```
Date="$2"
if [ ${#Date} -ne 6 ] || [[ "$Date" != +([0-9]) ]] 
then 
        echo "Erreur  : $2 - Format date incorrect"
        echo "Usage   : AAAAMM - date composée de 6 chiffres (4 pour l'année et 2 pour le mois)"
        echo "Exemple : $0 D 200806"
        exit 3
fi
```

---

```
bash: line 118: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
bash: line 118: syntax error near `+(['
bash: line 118: `       if [[ "$NbMois" != +([0-9]) ]] || [ "$NbMois" -lt 0 ] || [ "$NbMois" -gt 99 ]'
```

the few lines of the code where i have this error...:

```
NbMois="$2"
if [[ "$NbMois" != +([0-9]) ]] || [ "$NbMois" -lt 0 ] || [ "$NbMois" -gt 99 ]
then
    echo "Erreur  : $2 - Nombre de mois incorrect"
    echo "Usage   : Entier numérique compris entre 0 et 99"
    echo "Exemple : $0 N 14"
    exit 3
fi
```

Comment: please paste your code snippet as code (four spaces) to keep indentation/formatting and not as quote with ">". also mention the line numbers from the original script.

Comment: What is the bash version on the remote machine?

Comment: @choroba GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote machine has an older version of bash. You have to enable extended patterns by prepending the following line into the script:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

The reqex operator in bash is `=~`.

```
Date="$2"
if [[ ! "$D" =~ ^[0-9]{6}$ ]];then
then 
    echo "Erreur  : $2 - Format date incorrect"
    echo "Usage   : AAAAMM - date composée de 6 chiffres (4 pour l'année et 2 pour le mois)"
    echo "Exemple : $0 D 200806"
    exit 3
fi
```

Comment: bash: line 118: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
bash: line 118: syntax error near `+(['
bash: line 118: `       if [[ "$NbMois" != +([0-9]) ]] || [ "$NbMois" -lt 0 ] || [ "$NbMois" -gt 99 ]'